# Querying custom taxonomy on category-specific page is overwritten by function

Tags: pre-get-posts

**BACKGROUND:**

Website is for leasing properties. Owners edit the ID of the property often. To fix this, I had to create a custom field. They needed the order on the archive page to display based on that custom field.

Property ID example is 1017 Seattle

On a specific category page, vacation ID=2042, they want the order of the posts to be alphabetical so:

- 1092 Aberdeen
- 1004 Olympia
- 1017 Seattle

The city names are actually custom taxonomies aptly named 'city'

*Here is the code for the "solve_order" function:*

```
// Order the posts in archives page to DESC
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_change_sort_order'); 
function my_change_sort_order($query){
    if(is_archive()):
     //If you wanted it for the archive of a custom post type use: is_post_type_archive( $post_type )
       //Set the order ASC or DESC
       $query->set( 'order', 'DESC' );
       //Set the orderby
       // It was orderby ID, I changed to title so that it will display correctly for what Shannon was asking.
       $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value_num name' );
       $query->set( 'meta_key', 'solve_order' );
    endif;    
};
```

*Here is the code on my category-2042.php page*

```
$args = array ( 'category' => 2042, 'posts_per_page' => 3, 'orderby' => 'meta_value', 'meta_key' => 'vacation_order', 'order' => 'ASC');
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach( $myposts as $post ) :  setup_postdata($post);
```

**THE PROBLEM**

For some reason, the function is overwriting the sort order of my posts on the vacation page. It displays 3 posts, or however many I put in, but it is still displaying the posts based on the "solve_order" meta_key vs the "vacation_order" meta_key. When I remove the function from my functions.php, it sorts correctly but breaks the rest of the site.

There is a previous question asked that is similar but, the answer was accidentally based on not reading the question thoroughly, they didn't see it was based on is_author() and thought it was based on is_archive().

**THE GOAL**

For it to be automated and display alphabetically based on custom taxonomy "city" on the vacation category page.

Regular Archive Page sorting via the function: http://onlocation.com/category/00001-airport-terminal/

Category Specific Page trying to sort via city taxonomy: http://onlocation.com/category/00543-vacation-rental/

Comment: Pieter, you're right. I tried changing the function to is_main_query() vs. is_archive() and then creating a duplicate function for the vacation_order and changing is_main_query to is_category(2042) and it seems to have worked. Now the only problem is the nav_menu has disappeared.

Comment: Here is the code I ended up with, which worked for me:

`    // Order the posts in archives page to DESC
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_change_sort_order'); 
    function my_change_sort_order($query){
        if(is_main_query()):
...
        endif;    
    };

// Order the posts in archives page to DESC
 add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_vacation_change_sort_order'); 
     function my_vacation_change_sort_order($query){
         if(is_category(2042)):
            ...
         endif;    
     }; `

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure if this will work, but have you tried querying the meta key in a seperate array inside the $args? For instance...

```
$args = array(
    'category' => 2042,
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'meta_query' => array (
        array (
          'key' => 'vacation_order',
          'compare' => 'IN'
        )
    ) );        

$new_query = new WP_Query( $args );
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach( $myposts as $post ) :  setup_postdata($post);
```

Was just a thought, as I said, not tested.